# sed script to print the first three words in each line

Tags: scripting, sed

I wonder how can I do the following thing with sed:
I need to keep only the first three words in each line.
For example, the following text:

```
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy bear
the blue lion is hungry
```

will be transformed in:

```
the quick brown
the blue lion
```

Comment: Note: when I added the question I forgot about "cut", which is the right tool to do the job: cut -f-3 -d" "

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `cut` like this:

```
cut -d' ' -f1-3
```

Comment: thanks. Indeed, I should have realized that it's a task for "cut", not for "sed". cut -f -3 inputfile.

Comment: Note `-f-3` is equivalent to `-f1-3`. That is `-3` will mean: all fields up to `3`.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks. I suspect I'll continue writing `-f1-3` though for clarity and because I'll forget the abbreviation!

Answer (score 18):

In awk you can say:

```
{print $1, $2, $3}
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks was looking for something to strip out the first word from a command of running ec2 instances, was messing around with sed and cut but awk is perfect for my requirements

Comment: thanks for this but it is a bit unclear, so I would have added `awk -vORS=' ' '{print $1}'` (where I use `-vORS=' '` since I want the words space separated.

Comment: Golfing: `awk '{NF=3}1'`

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest `awk` in this situation:

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3}' ./infile
```

Answer (score 4):

```
% (echo "A B C D E F G H";echo "a b c d e f g h") | sed -E 's/([^\s].){3}//'
```

I put the "-E" in there for OS X compatibility. Other Unix systems may or may not need it.

edit: damnitall - brainfart.  use this:

```
% sed -E 's/(([^ ]+ ){3}).*/\1/' <<END
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy bear
the blue lion is hungry
END

the quick brown 
the blue lion
```

Comment: +1 for a more concise solution with `sed` - although you might want to edit your post to remove your first attempt.

Answer (score 2):

Just using the shell

```
while read -r a b c d
do
  echo $a $b $c
done < file
```

Ruby(1.9)+

```
ruby -ane 'print "#{$F[0]} #{$F[1]} #{$F[2]}\n"' file
```

Comment: `'puts $F[0..2].join " "'` is somewhat more concise for the ruby.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a sed script, you can try:

```
echo "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy bear" | sed 's/^\([a-zA-Z]\+\ [a-zA-Z]\+\ [a-zA-Z]\+\).*/\1/'
```

But I think it would be easier using cut:

```
echo "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy bear" | cut -d' ' -f1,2,3
```

Comment: Cut doesn't cope with variations in the whitespacing used.

Comment: Nor does including one literal space in the `sed` command (which doesn't need to be escaped, by the way).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an ugly one with `sed`:

```
$ echo the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy bear | sed 's|^\(\([^[:space:]]\+[[:space:]]\+\)\{2\}[^[:space:]]\+\).*|\1|'
the quick brown
```

Answer (score 0):

If Perl is an option:

`perl -lane 'print "$F[0] $F[1] $F[2]"' file`
or
`perl -lane 'print join " ", @F[0..2]' file`